Verifying if a Function is a Radon-Nikodym Derivative for changing the numeraire
I am analyzing the following function within a financial mathematics framework:
$$
f(t) = \dfrac{B(S; S) \cdot m(t)}{B(t; S) \cdot m(S)}
$$
where:
$$
B(t; S) := \mathbb{E}_{t}^{\mathbb{P}} \left[\exp\left(-\int_{t}^{S}r_{f}(u)\, du\right)\right]
$$
and
$$
m(t) := \exp\left(\int_{0}^{t} r_{f}(u)\, du\right)
$$
Definitions:

$B(t; S)$ represents the price at time $t$ of a zero-coupon bond maturing at time $S>t$, given the information available at time $t$.
$m(t)$ is a discount factor related to the risk-free interest rate $r_f(t)$.

I want to determine whether this function can be considered as the Radon-Nikodym derivative $$\dfrac{d\mathbb{P}^{S}}{d\mathbb{P}}_{|\mathfrak{F}_{t}}$$
where $\mathbb{P}^{S}$ is the new probability measure associated to the new numeraire $B(t;S)$ and $\mathfrak{F}_{t}$ is a filtration.
My Approach:
Notice that in order to define $\dfrac{B(S; S) \cdot m(t)}{B(t; S) \cdot m(S)}$ as the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\dfrac{d\mathbb{P}^{S}}{d\mathbb{P}}_{|\mathfrak{F}_{t}}$, it is sufficient to verify that:

The expression is a $\mathbb{P}^{S}$-martingale.
It has a $\mathbb{P}^{S}$-expectation equal to one.

Here’s how these conditions are met:

$B(S; S)$ is equal to 1.
The expectation of $\frac{m(t)}{m(S)}$ under $\mathbb{P}^{S}$ is equal to $B(t; S)$.

These properties ensure that the expression has a $\mathbb{P}^{S}$-expectation equal to one. Moreover, since the expression is equal to one for every $t$, this implies that it is also a $\mathbb{P}^{S}$-martingale.
Questions:

Verification: Is my understanding correct that verifying the martingale property and the expectation is sufficient to establish that this function is a Radon-Nikodym derivative?
Martingale Proof: How can I rigorously prove that the expression is indeed a \$mathbb{P}^{S}$-martingale?
Additional Considerations: Are there other properties or conditions that I should consider in this context?

Any feedback or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Can you confirm what the $|\mathfrak F_t$ in the R-N derivative is intended to mean?

I note that
$$f(t) = \frac{D(S)}{\mathbb E^\mathbb P _t[D(S)]}$$
where
$$D(S) = \exp\left(-\int_0^Sr_f(u)du\right).$$
What you actually want is to use $f(0)$ as your Radon-Nikodym derivative. All that is needed for this to be a Radon-Nikodym derivative between probability measures is that it is non-negative and $E^\mathbb P _0 [f(0)] = 1$, which is plainly true. For more info, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_measure.
